# Fill columns based on groups and conditions in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Consider the below Pandas `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make': ['Tesla','Tesla','Tesla','Toyota','Ford','Ford','Ford','BMW','BMW','BMW','Mercedes','Mercedes','Mercedes','Jeep','Jeep','Jeep'],
                   'Type': ['Model X','Model X','Model X','Corolla','Bronco','Bronco','Mustang','3 Series','3 Series','7 Series','C-Class','C-Class','S-Class','Wrangler','Compass','Patriot'],
                   'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020,2020,2021,2020],
                   'Price': [85000, 90000, 95000, 20000, 35000, 35000, 45000, 40000, 40000, 65000, 50000, 50000, 75000,60000,45000,40000],
                   'Color': ['White','White','White','Red','Blue','Blue','Yellow','Silver','Silver','Black','White','White','Black','Grey','Brown','Green'],
                   'Code'  : ['TSLABG','TSLA',None,'TYTA','FRD','_BG',None,None,'BMW','BMW','MercedesBG','Mercedes_BG','MercedesBG',None,'_BG','JeepBG']
                  })
```

```
df
     Make   Type       Year Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla   Model X    2015 85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla   Model X    2015 90000   White   TSLA
2   Tesla   Model X    2015 95000   White   None
3   Toyota  Corolla    2017 20000   Red     TYTA
4    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD 
5    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    _BG
6    Ford   Mustang    2020 45000   Yellow  None
7     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  None
8     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
9     BMW   7 Series   2017 65000   Black   BMW
10 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
11 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   Mercedes_BG
12 Mercedes S-Class    2020 75000   Black   MercedesBG
13   Jeep   Wrangler   2020 60000   Grey    None
14   Jeep   Compass    2021 45000   Brown   _BG
15   Jeep   Patriot    2020 40000   Green   JeepBG
```

I am trying to update the `Code` Column based on the `Make`. If `Code` column is having `None`, it must be  correctly filled based on the other values of  `Code` column for the same `Make`. In other words if any `Make` is having `Code` defined in the `Code` column that value should be used to fill `None` value in the `Code` column, also if  `BG` or `_BG`  is appended to any code value of the same `Make`, all the `Code` values should be appended with the `BG` or `_BG` respectively  for the same `Make` with `BG` taking precedence over `_BG`

Since `BMW` is having no `BG` or `_BG` for already existing `BMW` code values, when replacing the `None` it doesn't get appended with `BG` or `_BG`. For Ford `_BG` is present for one of the values and `FRD` is present for another value so all `Code` values of `Ford` should be `FRD_BG`.

For Mercedes there are `Code` values with `BG`  appended to the Code, so if any `Code` value is having `_` prepended to the `BG`, the `_` should be removed from the `Code` Value

Similarly for `Jeep` I am expecting the output to be `JeepBG` for all the `Jeep` `Make` since if 'BG' and '_BG' comes up `BG` takes priority over `_BG`

Each make would definitely have a code value specified in one of the entries of the group.

The solution I have tried

```
code = (df['Code'].str.split('(BG|_BG)', expand=True).add_prefix('part').replace('-', None).groupby(df['Make']).transform('first').fillna('').agg(''.join, axis=1))
df['Code'] = code
df
```

The output I got has `_BG` being populated for all the `Jeep` `Code` and it should've been `JeepBG`.

```
     Make   Type       Year Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla   Model X    2015 85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla   Model X    2015 90000   White   TSLABG
2   Tesla   Model X    2015 95000   White   TSLABG
3   Toyota  Corolla    2017 20000   Red     TYTA
4    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
5    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
6    Ford   Mustang    2020 45000   Yellow  FRD_BG
7     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
8     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
9     BMW   7 Series   2017 65000   Black   BMW
10 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
11 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
12 Mercedes S-Class    2020 75000   Black   MercedesBG
13   Jeep   Wrangler   2020 60000   Grey    _BG
14   Jeep   Compass    2021 45000   Brown   _BG
15   Jeep   Patriot    2020 40000   Green   _BG
```

The expected output is:

```
     Make   Type       Year Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla   Model X    2015 85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla   Model X    2015 90000   White   TSLABG
2   Tesla   Model X    2015 95000   White   TSLABG
3   Toyota  Corolla    2017 20000   Red     TYTA
4    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
5    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
6    Ford   Mustang    2020 45000   Yellow  FRD_BG
7     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
8     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
9     BMW   7 Series   2017 65000   Black   BMW
10 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
11 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
12 Mercedes S-Class    2020 75000   Black   MercedesBG
13   Jeep   Wrangler   2020 60000   Grey    JeepBG
14   Jeep   Compass    2021 45000   Brown   JeepBG
15   Jeep   Patriot    2020 40000   Green   JeepBG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this in steps, since there are many requirements

First, let's define columns `is_bg` and `isbg`, which will aid us throughout the process:

```
grouper = df.groupby('Make')['Code']
df['is_bg'] = grouper.transform(lambda s: s.str.endswith('_BG').astype(bool))
df['isbg']  = grouper.transform(lambda s: s.str.endswith('BG') 
                                   & ~s.str.endswith('_BG').astype(bool))
```

Now, let's remove `_BG` and `BG` suffixes so that we can find the unique identifier for each `Code`:

```
df.loc[df.isbg,  'Code'] = df.loc[df.isbg,  'Code'].str[:-2]
df.loc[df.is_bg, 'Code'] = df.loc[df.is_bg, 'Code'].str[:-3]
```

Now, we create a mapper and assign:

```
mapper = df.groupby('Make').apply(lambda s:
                           # Retrieve the unique code
                           s.loc[s['Code'].str.len() > 1,'Code'].iloc[0] + 
                           # Append BG if `isbg`
                           ('BG' if s.isbg.any() else 
                           # Otherwise, append _BG if `is_bg`
                           ('_BG' if s.is_bg.any() else '')))
df['New_Code'] = df['Make'].map(mapper)
```

Notice that there's an assumption here that for each `Make`, we'll only have one entry in `Code` that, after having `_BG` and `BG` removed, will NOT be either whitespace or `None`. If this is not true, then the problem is ambiguous and you'll need to explore how to find the unique Code identifier.

---

```
        Make      Type  Year  Price      Code   isbg  is_bg    New_Code
0      Tesla   Model X  2015  85000      TSLA   True  False      TSLABG
1      Tesla   Model X  2015  90000      TSLA  False  False      TSLABG
2      Tesla   Model X  2015  95000      None  False  False      TSLABG
3     Toyota   Corolla  2017  20000      TYTA  False  False        TYTA
4       Ford    Bronco  2018  35000       FRD  False  False      FRD_BG
5       Ford    Bronco  2018  35000            False   True      FRD_BG
6       Ford   Mustang  2020  45000      None  False  False      FRD_BG
7        BMW  3 Series  2015  40000      None  False  False         BMW
8        BMW  3 Series  2015  40000       BMW  False  False         BMW
9        BMW  7 Series  2017  65000       BMW  False  False         BMW
10  Mercedes   C-Class  2018  50000  Mercedes   True  False  MercedesBG
11  Mercedes   C-Class  2018  50000  Mercedes  False   True  MercedesBG
12  Mercedes   S-Class  2020  75000  Mercedes   True  False  MercedesBG
13      Jeep  Wrangler  2020  60000      None  False  False      JeepBG
14      Jeep   Compass  2021  45000            False   True      JeepBG
15      Jeep   Patriot  2020  40000      Jeep   True  False      JeepBG
```

Comment: Yes at least one of them would be code and if you replace BG and  _BG in the group with "" it would be the code and only None values left, so you can bfill and ffill the groups to fill the None values and then add the _BG or BG values to the groups

Comment: No need to `bfill` or `ffill` in this case ;) I suggested a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

remove _BG and BG / fill value except BG

```
s = df['Code'].str.replace(r'[_]?BG', '', regex=True).replace({'': None}).groupby(df['Make']).transform('first')
```

`s`

```
0         TSLA
1         TSLA
2         TSLA
3         TYTA
4          FRD
5          FRD
6          FRD
7          BMW
8          BMW
9          BMW
10    Mercedes
11    Mercedes
12    Mercedes
13        Jeep
14        Jeep
15        Jeep
```

extract BG and _BG and so on..

```
df1 = df['Code'].str.extract(r'[^_]+(BG)|(_BG)').groupby(df['Make']).ffill().groupby(df['Make']).bfill()
```

`df1`

```
    0   1
0   BG  NaN
1   BG  NaN
2   BG  NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN _BG
5   NaN _BG
6   NaN _BG
7   NaN NaN
8   NaN NaN
9   NaN NaN
10  BG  _BG
11  BG  _BG
12  BG  _BG
13  BG  _BG
14  BG  _BG
15  BG  _BG
```

fillna df1 and string concat

```
df.assign(Code=s.str.cat(df1[0].fillna(df1[1]).fillna('')))
```

`out`

```
    Make        Type        Year    Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla       Model X     2015    85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla       Model X     2015    90000   White   TSLABG
2   Tesla       Model X     2015    95000   White   TSLABG
3   Toyota      Corolla     2017    20000   Red     TYTA
4   Ford        Bronco      2018    35000   Blue    FRD_BG
5   Ford        Bronco      2018    35000   Blue    FRD_BG
6   Ford        Mustang     2020    45000   Yellow  FRD_BG
7   BMW         3 Series    2015    40000   Silver  BMW
8   BMW         3 Series    2015    40000   Silver  BMW
9   BMW         7 Series    2017    65000   Black   BMW
10  Mercedes    C-Class     2018    50000   White   MercedesBG
11  Mercedes    C-Class     2018    50000   White   MercedesBG
12  Mercedes    S-Class     2020    75000   Black   MercedesBG
13  Jeep        Wrangler    2020    60000   Grey    JeepBG
14  Jeep        Compass     2021    45000   Brown   JeepBG
15  Jeep        Patriot     2020    40000   Green   JeepBG
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Panda Kim's solution

```
lhs = df['Code'].str.replace(r'[_]?BG', '', regex=True).replace({'': None}).groupby(df['Make']).transform('first')

rhs = df['Code'].str.extract(r'[^_]+(BG)|(_BG)',expand =False).groupby(df['Make']).ffill().groupby(df['Make']).bfill()

rhs = rhs[0].fillna((rhs[1]).fillna(''))

df['Code'] = lhs + rhs
```